# How to get Id property from list items

Tags: c#, list, xamarin

I am using `IList` called Categories, and it contains items of type `FER`, and I want to get the `Id` assigned to each item in the List. I wrote the code below, but it returns a boolean and the `Id` is of type `Long`

please let me know how to get the id of each item in the `IList`

**code**

```
c =_rec.Categories.Where(i => i.Id);
```

Comment: `_rec.Select(x => x.id)`?

Comment: The xamarin tag is not relevant here my friend

Answer (score 3):

The Where in linq is used to evaluate an expression, that's why your result is returning true. You should use .Select() if you'd like to return a specific property from your object. The below will return a list of type Id

```
// All values in a list
var ids = _rec.Categories.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

// Single Value if not a list
var id = _rec.Categories.Select(x => x.Id);

// Query for a specific category and return Id
var id = _rec.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 123).Select(x => x.Id);
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer.

Comment: would you please tell how can I modify the code you poste dose I can get only one value NOT a list?? I do not want to use ToList because it is only one value

Comment: I don´t get what you mean by `//Single value if not in a list`. Your second example will just return an iterator that - as it iterates the same collection - returns the same elements as the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Where does not return a boolean, it needs a boolean type which you are not providing.
Example:

```
var category = _rec.Categories.Where(i => i.Id == 1).SingleOrDefault();
```

To get a list of Ids do

```
var ids = _rec.Categories.Select(i => i.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: In fact `Where` does not need a bool, but a `Predicate`, which is a `Func<bool>`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere true true, thought it would be easier to chew if I'd write it that way.